# How to refresh jsgrid based in a plain text in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, jsgrid

I'm trying to create a dynamic datagrid using jsgrid based in a plain text.

I know I could use the option "editable" and use the own jsgrid tools to implement a dynamic datagrid, but this project is focused in a specific area where most of users are used to use plain text to copy and to archive the data in question, so it's mandatory to me to use plain text to keep easy to input and to output data whenever necessary.

Until now, I'm simply writing the data grid over again every time the input is changed, but obviously as the input becomes larger, more slow is this writing.

Here the link for tests: http://balaiomtg.ligaos.net/

Try this as input:

```
1 Zedruu the Greathearted
1 Steel Golem
1 Illusions of Grandeur
1 Pyromancer's Swath
1 Celestial Dawn
1 Gilded Drake
1 Vedalken Plotter
1 Political Trickery
1 Shifting Borders
1 Phyrexian Metamorph
1 Psychosis Crawler
1 Mirror-Sigil Sergeant
1 Yosei, the Morning Star
1 Keiga, the Tide Star
1 Consecrated Sphinx
1 Sun Titan
1 Niv-Mizzet, the Firemind
1 Numot, the Devastator
1 Eternal Dragon
1 Quicksilver Gargantuan
1 Chancellor of the Spires
1 Bogardan Hellkite
1 Iona, Shield of Emeria
1 Hinder
1 Spell Crumple
1 Forbid
1 Decree of Silence
1 Journey to Nowhere
1 Oblivion Ring
1 Detention Sphere (RTR)
1 Nevermore
1 Orim's Thunder
1 Dismantling Blow
1 Hallowed Burial
1 Terminus
1 Austere Command
1 Wild Research
1 Idyllic Tutor
1 Tezzeret the Seeker
1 Mystic Remora
1 Rhystic Study
1 Fact or Fiction
1 Future Sight
1 Aeon Chronicler
1 Sphinx's Revelation
1 Lightning Greaves
1 Whispersilk Cloak
1 Crystal Shard
1 Spreading Seas
1 Paradox Haze
1 Copy Enchantment
1 Venser the Sojourner
1 Sphere of the Suns
1 Vessel of Endless Rest
1 Darksteel Ingot
1 Coalition Relic
1 Expedition Map
1 Journeyer's Kite
1 Pilgrim's Eye
1 Solemn Simulacrum
1 Command Tower
1 Homeward Path
1 Reliquary Tower
1 Kher Keep
1 Terramorphic Expanse
1 Evolving Wilds
1 Celestial Colonnade
1 Glacial Fortress
1 Mystic Gate
1 Flooded Strand
1 Azorius Chancery
1 Hallowed Fountain
1 Battlefield Forge
1 Arid Mesa
1 Rugged Prairie
1 Boros Garrison
1 Sacred Foundry
1 Cascade Bluffs
1 Steam Vents
1 Izzet Boilerworks
1 Shivan Reef
1 Vivid Meadow
1 Vivid Crag
1 Vivid Creek
1 Tolaria West
1 Mistveil Plains
6 Island
5 Plains
3 Mountain
1 Bruna, the Fading Light*
1 Gisela, the Broken Blade
1 Knight of the White Orchid
1 Thalia's Lancers
1 Sol Ring*
1 Thran Dynamo*
1 Caged Sun
1 Hedron Archive*
1 Worn Powerstone*
1 Pearl Medallion
1 Grand Abolisher
1 Serra Avenger*
```

EDIT: set a larger sample to input.

Comment: I'm sure the issue is clear. The demo works nice.

Comment: I edited the input for testing. The first time the grid is wrote, it's ok is takes its time, but every change demands the same amount of time or more.

Comment: Have you checked what takes the most of the time? Is it the jsgrid code that takes too long? Try to profile the rendering, to see what takes most of the time, this should give us the answer.